# Change constant, var value in php file

Tags: php

I'm writing my own tiny deployment script and I need to change db login and password in db.php file when copying it to remote host. Is it possible to change variable/constant value without hand-made analyzing (preg_replace etc.) text of php file?

I know that PHP have `tokenizer`, but I have no clue how to use it.

Please help me with some samples.

Any help and suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not separate development and production `db.php` and copy/use the suitable one in each place?

Comment: Why not store it in one of the dozens of standard file formats already used to configure software?

Comment: @miku, I don't want anybody (involved into development process) know login and password for production database access.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, you mean something like .ini formatted configuration files? Frankly speaking it is nice idea, but I have to add caching layer (cache into memory) to prevent parsing configuration file each request. Also I should add cache cleaner to my deployment script.

Answer (score 2):

A simple `str_replace` would suffice, for example:

```
$config = file_get_contents('config.dist');
$config = str_replace(
              array('##USERNAME##', '##PASSWORD##'),
              array($realUsername, $realPassword),
              $config);
file_put_contents('config.php', $config);
```

where `config.dist` would look something like this:

```
<?php
$username = '##USERNAME##';
$password = '##PASSWORD##';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find phing overkill but it is quite useful. http://phing.info/trac/